# How do I change hover to click?

Tags: jquery

Right now it works on hover. I need to make it work on click only so it works properly on a mobile device.

.nav needs to be #access, but I get lost after that. What do I change .nav to match up with my css which is from wordpress?

I'm trying to get http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/378_tessa/tessa-lt-dropdowns-21c7868/index.html to work with wordpress.

http://jsfiddle.net/scottbotkins/dbW2Q/

```
    var ww = document.body.clientWidth;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav li a").each(function() {
        if ($(this).next().length > 0) {
            $(this).addClass("parent");
        };
    })

    $(".toggleMenu").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(".nav").toggle();
    });
    adjustMenu();
})

$(window).bind('resize orientationchange', function() {
    ww = document.body.clientWidth;
    adjustMenu();
});

var adjustMenu = function() {
    if (ww < 768) {
        $(".toggleMenu").css("display", "inline-block");
        if (!$(".toggleMenu").hasClass("active")) {
            $(".nav").hide();
        } else {
            $(".nav").show();
        }
        $(".nav li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
        $(".nav li a.parent").unbind('click').bind('click', function(e) {
            // must be attached to anchor element to prevent bubbling
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent("li").toggleClass("hover");
        });
    } 
    else if (ww >= 768) {
        $(".toggleMenu").css("display", "none");
        $(".nav").show();
        $(".nav li").removeClass("hover");
        $(".nav li a").unbind('click');
        $(".nav li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
            // must be attached to li so that mouseleave is not triggered when hover over submenu
            $(this).toggleClass('hover');
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple work around is like remove

```
 #access ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

from css and

add this jQuery code

```
$('#menu-navigation li').click(function(){
       $(this).find('.sub-menu').show();
        $(this).siblings().find('.sub-menu').hide();
});
```

You will have to alter the code to get what you are looking for.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. This shows exactly what I want, however I need to change .nav to #access something. http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/378_tessa/tessa-lt-dropdowns-21c7868/index.html

Comment: you want to show the submenu only when clicking the main menu rite?

Comment: correct, it's 3 levels like the webdesigntuts one shows. I'm using their exact code. I thought it would be simple as changing .nav to #access ul or something like that.

Comment: if you want the same feature in the link given, you will have to change the css only.